# mongodb select where all subfields have specific value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

With following entries:

```
{id : "a1", b: {"123":1, "345":2}}
{id : "a2", b: {"123":null, "345":2, "567":3}}
{id : "a3", b: {"123":null, "345":null, "567":null}}
```

How can I query all, that have all sub fields of "b" being null?